VS-Code : Cannot activate the 'Git' extension because it depends on the 'Git Base' extension which is disabled. Scanning folder for git repositories
I'm connecting via Remote host when i start my vscode on that time right side showing below error: "Cannot activate the 'Git' extension because it depends on the 'Git Base' extension which is disabled."
when i made any changes not showing files in source control, only showing Scanning folder for git repositories.
How to fix this error in VS code i have attached my issues in screenshot
I want to fix this error
enter image description here enter image description here

Please put the images directly in the question.

I encountered the same problem.
The issue seems to have occurred because you upgraded your vscode version.
However, the server was not updated synchronously, and I am also unsure how to update vscode on the server.
But if you delete vscode on the server, vscode will reinstall automatically.
Here are the steps:
# 1. entry yourself server
# 2. delete vscode-server
rm -r ~/.vscode-server

Then, use vscode to reconnect to the server, and it will automatically download vscode on the server.
I have a question: If you use this method, all plugins will need to be reinstalled, and the previous plugins will be lost.
